# Read all projects within Project Online using web part Sharepoint

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

Can we get data of all projects from Project Online in SharePoint Site? So far as I understand we can get data of list like this:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList issueList = web.GetList("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/demo/Sample Project 1/Lists/Issues/AllItems.aspx");
```

Do you have any some good tutorial? I am new on web part SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use REST API for this.

1) Get All Projects information from Project Online

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects
```

2) Get Project GUID

```
http:///_api/ProjectData/Projects/?$select=ProjectId
```

3) Get Specific Project information based on GUID

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')
```

4) Get Assignment Information of a Project (Tasks Assigned)

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')/Assignments
```

5) Get Assignments based on user

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')/Assignments?$filter=ResourceName eq '<Name>'
```

6) Get Tasks of a Project

```
http://<pwa_site>/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'<GUID here>')/Tasks
```

Reference Link: https://www.dsouzajoel.com/2016/10/21/project-online-api-list/